# Can't update data in firebase database when it's updated in the gmail of the user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in my android app. the user signs in the app using gmail. at the first time the users sign in the app I store their data in the database. after the first time when the user signs in the app the app should updated the user data in the database if it has changed in gmail. The problem is that after changing the user name of the mail in gmail `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()` returns the old user name not the new one.

this is my code :

```
userName = user.getDisplayName();
userImage = user.getPhotoUrl().toString();
userEmail = user.getEmail();
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getUid()).exists()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("userName", userName);
            map.put("userImage", userImage);
            map.put("userEmail", userEmail);
            map.put("points", 0);
            map.put("acceptedQuestions", 0);
            map.put("refusedQuestions", 0);
            map.put("acceptedLessons", 0);
            map.put("refusedLessons", 0);
            map.put("userType", userType);
            myRef.child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(map);
        }
        else {
            currentUserReference =  myRef.child(mAuth.getUid());
            currentUserReference.child("userName").setValue(userName);
            currentUserReference.child("userImage").setValue(userImage);
            currentUserReference.child("userType").setValue(userType);
            Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "user name is : " + userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

what I wonder is that userName variable returns the old userName not the new one

Comment: did you update in the firebase user?

Comment: the user is signed with gmail only not with email and password so I don't need to update anything

Comment: yes, i know but you retrieve the information form the firebase user.

Comment: Are you saying that `user.getDisplayName();` returns the old display name? If so, the problem is unrelated to the database and it might help to clean up the code.

Comment: I have cleaned the code many times but the problem still exists